# getting java.io.InterruptedIOException while implementing instant search in android using RxJava2 and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

So I am trying to implement instant search using rxjava2 and retrofit,
the process is simple, as soon as the user changes the text `publish.onNext()` is called (publish is a `PublishSubject` object).
I have added filter and debounce and switch map operators to facilitate search from the server when text's length is greater than a threshold and call is not made with successive input simultaneously.

This is the code :

```
subject = PublishSubject.create();
    getCompositeDisposable().add(subject
            .filter(s -> s.length() >= 3)
            .debounce(300,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .switchMap(s -> getDataManager().getHosts(
                    getDataManager().getDeviceToken(),
                    s).observeOn(Schedulers.io()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(hostResponses -> {
                getMvpView().hideEditLoading();
                if (hostResponses.size() != 0) {
                    if (this.hostResponses != null)
                        this.hostResponses.clear();
                    this.hostResponses = hostResponses;
                    getMvpView().setHostView(getHosts(hostResponses));
                } else {
                    getMvpView().onFieldError("No host found");
                }

            }, throwable -> {
                getMvpView().hideEditLoading();
                if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                   HttpException exception = (HttpException)throwable;
                    if (exception.code() == 401) {
                        getMvpView().onError(R.string.code_expired,
                                BaseUtils.TOKEN_EXPIRY_TAG);
                    }
                }

            })
    );
```

Now my code is working fine, I am achieving what I need 
but I am getting a bug when I enter a long string and press backspace button, what happens is that when my AutoCompleteTextView's text is cleared, an exception is thrown

Here is the stacktrace of the exception :

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted  
at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)  
at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:76)  
at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:180)  
at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:216)  
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.finishRequest(Http1Codec.java:166)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:84) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)  
at com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor.intercept(StethoInterceptor.java:56)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)  
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)  
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)  
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)  
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)  
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)  
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)  
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700)  
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)  
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700)  
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:45)  
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700)  
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSwitchMap$SwitchMapObserver.onNext(ObservableSwitchMap.java:126)  
at io.reactivex.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:111)  
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDebounceTimed$DebounceTimedObserver.emit(ObservableDebounceTimed.java:140)  
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDebounceTimed$DebounceEmitter.run(ObservableDebounceTimed.java:165)  
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)  
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)  
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762
```

Comment: This is an unfortunate situation with many blocking IO APIs that throw an exception if their connection/activity is cancelled asynchronously. You probably can't do much about it other than installing a [global error handler](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling) to prevent your entire app from crashing.

Comment: The problem is not that the app is crashing or anything, but as soon as this exception is raised, thread(most probably Schedulers.io()) is interrupted and after that when a user enters a search query nothing happens, how should i resolve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That inner `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` doesn't look right, given that you immediately move the element back to the main thread after that. It should be `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` there instead.

Also remove the `subscribeOn()` call just before your `subscribe` call as it should have no practical effect given that the chain is subscribed to a `PublishSubject` at the top.

```java
.switchMap(s -> getDataManager()
               .getHosts(getDataManager().getDeviceToken(), s)
//             .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   // <-------------------------
)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
//.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   // <--------------------------------------
.subscribe(hostResponses -> {
```

Comment: well i mistakenly used observeOn instead of subscribeOn inside switchmap that i understand and implemented, this was what i intended to do from start(when i encountered this problem), and ofcouse using subscribeon before subscribe in that case becomes redundant
but let's say i dont add subscribeOn in my switchmap and use it before subscribe outside, how is this approach different from the previous one as i use the latter approach by default with my network calls?

Comment: BTW your solution works, thanks!
I am just curious how calling subscribeOn inside switchmap and not outside resolves this threadinterrupted exception

Comment: `subscribeOn` affects **subscription time** side effects and Retrofit performs its network operation at that time. Since you have `switchMap`, it creates a fresh source every time thus there is a new **subscription time** everytime there is an upstream item to be mapped. If it is outside of such mapper, it will likely have no real effect. You'd usually get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` but in your case, the `debounce` and its `computation` `Scheduler` emission moved the network call outside the UI thread.

Comment: Okay! i get it now, That was insightful.
Thank you!